# Why is this JS function running when it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

Ok, so, pardon any mistake I may have made, since I'm still a beginner.

What I am trying to do is creating a drop-down menu for a website. I did manage to get it to appear on mouseover and disappear on mouseout, but I wanted to try and add a timeout to the disappearing part; problem is that as soon as I move my mouse outside of the top "gallery" part, the function to hide the menu starts running, even if I am still within the confines of the "menu".

I can get it to work fine without the `setTimeout` part (i.e. the menu closes only when I mouseout from the dropdown or the always-visible "gallery" button), but, as soon as I add that, the whole function activates as soon as I mouse out from the top always-visible "gallery" button.

Please, excuse the myriad of classes since I am using TailwindCSS.

HTML:

```
<header class="fixed w-full bg-green-300 z-20">
  <nav class="flex justify-between h-full items-center">
      <div class="flex">
          <a href="index.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Home</a>
          <a href="About_us.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">About us</a>
          <!--This is the whole "menu"-->
          <div class="Gallery flex flex-col">
              <!--This is the top always-visible button-->
              <a href="Gallery.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Gallery</a>
              <!--This is the drop-down menu that's currently hidden-->
              <div class="GalleryDropdown absolute flex flex-col bg-green-300 text-center mt-14 hidden">
                  <a href="Bouquet_and_personal_items.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Bouquets</a>
                  <a href="Ceremonies.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Ceremonies</a>
                  <a href="Misc_arrangements.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Misc</a>
                  <a href="Receptions.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Receptions</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <a href="Contacts.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Contacts</a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
          <a href="index.html" class="p-4 hover:bg-red-200">Dark</a>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

JS:

```
//Gallery dropdown

    //gallery nav button
    const gButton = document.querySelector('.gallery');
    //gallery dropdown menu
    const gDrop = document.querySelector('.GalleryDropdown');

    //gallery dropdown activate
    gButton.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        gDrop.classList.remove('hidden');
    });

    gButton.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        setTimeout( () => { 
            gDrop.classList.add('hidden');
        }, 500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increase the time.
0.5 s is not to much to see effect of hiding.

```
 setTimeout(function() {...}, 2000)
```

This time is in milisecods. So 500 = 0.5s

Comment: This still doesn't solve my problem; the whole function starts running when it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` is an API (that means it will run asynchronously - only when the callstack is empty), so if you want to run your code synchronously (meaning the code will run in order from the first line to last) you could use `transition-delay: 1s;` in the `Hidden` css class instead of the `setTimeout`.

Other thing you could try is toggling classes with `.classList.toggle` instead of adding them and removing.